# A review of Structural Equation Modeling (SEM)

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I'm interested in community thoughts on Structural Equation Modeling (SEM). My application is primarily consumer psychology. From the introductory material I've read, SEM offers an researcher a mechanism to define relationships between observed and latent variables. I've read that it's biggest drawback is that if you don't have extensive domain expertise to back up your hypothesized structure, you're likely to get terrible results. I've also read that different software packages can arrive at different conclusions given the same model specification. I'd like to elicit some opinions by experts on the utility, reliability, pros and cons on SEM.

Edits:

1. I primarily come from a Bayesian background and prefer PyMC3.
2. I saw a [Medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/structural-equation-modeling-dca298798f4d) that outlined an SEM where various psychological tests and job performance metrics were aggregated incorporated into one cohesive model. It seems that defining a joint likelihood could become tedious, hence why various specialty tools like LAVAAN exist.
3. The Medium article noted that unless the model specification closely reflects reality, which is a tall order, SEM aren't great for predictive accuracy; they're best suited for giving a sanity check to your beliefs on how a system is structured (ie job performance being work ethic, intelligence, social aptitude, etc.)

Comment: While expert opinion is valuable, however opinion-based questions are beyond the scope of stats.SE.

Comment: "*SEM offers an researcher a mechanism to define relationships between observed and latent variables.*" This is true.

Comment: "*I primarily come from a Bayesian background and prefer PyMC3*." I don't see why you couldn't incorporate PyMC3 into parametrizing SEM's, but if you want a quick way of specifying SEMs and training them in Python there exists [semopy](https://semopy.com/).

Comment: One challenge I find with existing software packages is their assumption that the functional relationships are linear. I've built custom SEMs using [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) when nonlinearity was required.

Comment: Like many computation graphs with free parameters, SEMs can require a fair bit of data to get reliable estimates. There isn't a single rule that determines required sample size either. See [Wolf 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4334479/) for discussion of sample size.

Comment: The importance of domain knowledge is to narrow down the number of possible SEM models to hypothesize, which is related to, the number of possible directed acyclic graphs on a set of variables.

Comment: I've seen SEM models have excellent predictive accuracy, but not on high-variance data like that often found in the social sciences.

Comment: I just skimmed the Medium article and saw that semopy is mentioned. Notice Lavaan and semopy do not perfectly agree? There can be multiple reasons for this. One is the initialization of the parameters. Another is the choice of objective function. Yet another is the optimizer algorithm, including its hyperparameters.

Comment: [*The goal of Structural Equation Modeling is to model the relations between measured and latent variables, or between multiple latent variables.*](https://towardsdatascience.com/structural-equation-modeling-dca298798f4d). This is optional. SEMs are useful for latent variable modelling, but they don't require latent variables; all your variables could be measured. What is primarily required is 'structural form' or '[reduced form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_form)'.

Comment: Perhaps you could write down an answer based on your 9 comments?